# Enable autoplay HTML5 video in chrome

Tags: browser, video, javascript, html5

In my project I need to autoplay a HTML5 video in the browser when the page is loaded. I have tried a several javascript solutions but none of them work.

I read that the android browser blocks autoplay to prevent downloading a lot of data. Can be this blocking feature be turned off in browser/chrome/operation system settings?

I cannot find any working solution for how to enable autoplay. I have searched plenty of stackoverflow posts and many other sites ...

I am using android 4.1.1.

Comment: To close voters: this question seems legit. Though it's the dev asking, the question itself is *not* about development, but about browser/system settings, and thus of interest to "normal users" as well (as long as Peter is not asking about doing this from his app in a programatical way, of course).

Answer (score 4):

Bad news it seems. [Bug report on Google code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159336)

The most relevant post is this:

> Yes. It is as design. "autoplay" is disabled for Chrome for Android

It seems that Android 4+ changed the requirements for the `play()` method to require user interaction.

[Article on this issue](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/)

It's worth nothing that many comments refer to getting it to work with a hack/workaround, only to find it works on some devices and not others.  [Stack Overflow question on the coding side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758651/autostart-html5-video-using-android-4-browser). In this example the answer mentions:

> sample code that works on HTC and Samsung, but not Galaxy Nexus 4.1 (requires user interaction to play)

This seems to suggest, even with a workaround you have no guarantee it will actually work on a particular device / version of Android.

Apple have imposed the same restriction in Safari and iOS in general.

Answer (score 3):

This can be turned on/off in Chrome using flags. This is on the user end though and cannot be change in the browser from a website or app.

You can also do this in your own app using the api for webview or websettings and make "getMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false)" it is by default set to "(true)"

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html

In chrome you must go to chrome://flags then go down about 3 screens to

> **Disable gesture requirement for media playback.** Android
>
> Disable user gesture requirement for playing media elements. Activating this will allow autoplay to work.
>
> *disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-playback*
>
> [Enable](http://chrome://flags)